firebase foreground notification not showing in react-native ios
I am using  "react-native": "0.68.2", along with
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.11.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.11.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.11.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.11.0",
"@react-native-firebase/storage": "^14.11.0",
//To handle ios notifications
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",

I am trying to show and work around push notifications that are working fine on android both in background & foreground states. In the case of IOS, push notifications are not working on the foreground and I have tried many solutions including this solution too.
This is my firebase notification handling code:


const checkToken = async() => {
  if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener(
      "notification",
      onRemoteNotification
    );
    PushNotification.configure({
      onRegister: (token) => {},
      onNotification: (notification) => {
        if (
          notification.foreground &&
          (notification.userInteraction || notification.remote)
        ) {
          PushNotification.localNotification({
            channelId: "fcm_fallback_notification_channel",
            largeIcon: "ic_launcher",
            bigText: notification ? .message,
            title: notification ? .title,
            message: notification ? .message,
            picture: "",
            vibrate: true,
            playSound: true,
            soundName: "default",
          });
          props.onRefreshNotification(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
          if (props ? .userData ? .type === UserTypes.MY_USER)
            Alert.alert(notification ? .message);
        }
        PushNotificationIOS.addNotificationRequest({
          alertBody: notification.message || "No message",
          alertTitle: notification.title || "No title",
        });
        PushNotificationIOS ? .FetchResult ? .NoData &&
          notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS ? .FetchResult ? .NoData);
      },
      senderID: "1090501687137",
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      },
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
  } else {
    PushNotification.configure({
      onRegister: function(token) {},
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        props.onRefreshNotification(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        if (props ? .userData ? .type === UserTypes.MY_USER)
          Alert.alert(notification ? .message);
        PushNotification.createChannel({
            channelId: "fcm_fallback_notification_channel",
            channelName: "notificationGatewayTherapute",
            channelDescription: "YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION",
            playSound: true,
            soundName: "default",
            vibrate: true,
          },
          (created) => {
            console.log("Notification :: ", notification);
            props.onRefreshNotification(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
          }
        );

        PushNotification.localNotification({
          channelId: "2",
          foreground: true,
          largeIcon: "ic_launcher",
          largeIconUrl: "",
          smallIcon: "ic_notification",
          bigText: notification ? .message,
          subText: "This is a subText",
          bigPictureUrl: "",
          bigLargeIcon: "ic_launcher",
          bigLargeIconUrl: "",
          color: "red",
          vibrate: true,
          vibration: 1000,
          priority: "high",
          visibility: "private",
          ignoreInForeground: false,
          timeoutAfter: null,
          messageId: "google:message_id",
          invokeApp: true,
          category: "",
          subtitle: notification ? .message,
          id: 0,
          title: notification ? .title,
          message: notification ? .message,
          picture: "",
          userInfo: {},
          playSound: true,
          soundName: "default",
        });

        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      },
      senderID: "1090501687137",
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      },
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
  }

  messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp((notification) => {
    props.navigation.navigate(notification ? .data ? .redirectTo);
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      PushNotification.getApplicationIconBadgeNumber((currentBadge) => {
        PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(
          Math.max(0, currentBadge - 1)
        );
      });
    } else {
      PushNotificationIOS.getApplicationIconBadgeNumber((currentBadge) => {
        PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(
          Math.max(0, currentBadge - 1)
        );
      });
    }
  });

  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async(remoteMessage) => {
    props.onRefreshNotification(Math.rapopInitialNotificationndom() * 10 + 1);
    if (props ? .userData ? .type === UserTypes.MY_USER)
      Alert.alert(remoteMessage ? .notification ? .body);
  });
};



Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
